# Redirecting after saving form on Django

Tags: python, django

I am working on extending the webapp we're left off with after completing the official Django Tutorial.

One of the functionalities I am looking to add is the ability for users to add polls themselves.

I am struggling with getting the page to process the data and then redirect to the index page ('/polls').

When I submit a new poll as a logged in user, I am returned to my index page, which is supposed to show most recently published polls, or in the event of no polls, the message "No polls are available."

For some reason, I always see "No polls are available", but once I click to the index page via a link on the site, it displays all of my polls, including my most recently created one, data intact!

Any thoughts here? I think I have included the relevant info below but happy to supply more. Thanks in advance for any help/advice.

views.py

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Return the last five published questions."""
        return Poll.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:15]

@login_required
def add_poll(request):
    ChoiceFormSet = formset_factory(ChoiceForm, extra=3, min_num=2, validate_min=2)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PollForm(request.POST)
        formset = ChoiceFormSet(request.POST)
        if all([form.is_valid(), formset.is_valid()]):
            poll = form.save()
            for inline_form in formset:
                if inline_form.cleaned_data:
                    choice = inline_form.save(commit=False)
                    choice.question = poll
                    choice.save()
            return render(request, 'polls/index.html', {})
    else:
        form = PollForm()
        formset = ChoiceFormSet()

    return render(request, 'polls/add_poll.html', {'form': form, 'formset': formset})
```

add_poll.html

```
{% extends 'polls/base.html' %}

{% block title %}Add Poll{% endblock %}

{% block body_block %}
<form role="form"  id="poll_form" method="post" action="{% url 'polls:add_poll' %}">
<h2 class="form-signin-heading">Add a Poll</h2>

  {% csrf_token %}

  <table>
    {{ form }}
    {{ formset }}
  </table>

<br/>

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit">Create Poll</button>

</form>

{% endblock %}
```

index.html

```
{% extends 'polls/base.html' %}

{% block body_block %}
{% if latest_question_list %}
<ul>
  {% for poll in latest_question_list %}
  <li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' poll.id %}">{{ poll.question_text }}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
<p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from . import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/results/$', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    url(r'^add_poll/$', views.add_poll, name='add_poll'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>\d+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
    url(r'^profile_page/$', views.ProfileView.as_view(), name='profile_page'),
    url(r'^edit_profile/$', views.edit_profile, name='edit_profile'),
)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you save your form you are not redirecting.

Your are returning `'polls/index.html'` with empty `polls` data, that's why you always get "No polls are available". But this is very incorrect, you must follow the [Post/Redirect/Get (PRG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern, so instead of:

```
return render(request, 'polls/index.html', {})
```

do this:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:index'))
```

Comment: Thanks Todor, this makes sense. Would passing a context containing the polls list instead of {} in the original render function also get the job done in a situation like this?

Comment: Yes it will probably work. However you should *never do it*. You need to *always* redirect after a POST.

Comment: I agree with @Serafeim, it will work, but don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't do any redirect right now, you are just rendering your index template *with an empty* context (that's why you don't see anything). To redirect, you need to use HttpResponseRedirect when your form is valid.

So, please change line:

```
return render(request, 'polls/index.html', {})
```

(just over the `else`) to

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out. I had to change my html form to this:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'new_beam:beam_diagram' beam_id=1 %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```